# Want to export a javaScript Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require, module.exports

I want to export an Object and get always the same Error

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received function router
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:363:5)
at Function.from (node:buffer:323:9)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Web\node\Projekte\social\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:189:22)
at C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Web\node\Projekte\social\router\homeRouter.js:12:14
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Web\node\Projekte\social\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Web\node\Projekte\social\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Web\node\Projekte\social\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Web\node\Projekte\social\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Web\node\Projekte\social\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Web\node\Projekte\social\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)

data.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

let user = {
    'userName': '',
    'email': '',
    'password': ''
};

router.post('/', (request, response) => {
    user.userName = request.body.Username;
    user.email = request.body.email;
    user.password = request.body.password;
    console.log(user);
    response.redirect('/account');
})

module.exports = user;

module.exports = router;
```

homeRouter.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

var test = require('./data');


router.get('/', (request, response) => {
    const pathToFile = path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'home.ejs');

    //response.render(pathToFile);
    response.send(test);
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `module.exports = router;` overrides the previous export, `module.exports = user;`. If you want to export `user` then remove `module.exports = router;` from that file.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer I willtry it :)

Comment: Notice that this allows only a single user on the server, and anyone can read their password. Not sure about your use case, but you might want to look into sessions.

Comment: Yes its only one Object for one User. just for an better understanding of node. The next Step ist to implement a SQL Database. Anyway, Thank you Guys, it works :)